# Secure php voting without login

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Is there any method to make a secure php voting system? I would try by storing the IP addresses, but there are dynamic IPs. Someone clever could reconnect and vote twice. Cookies also are easy to crack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any way to track a user: cookies, session, IP, E-tags, localstorage etc. can all be circumvented.

If you add a login - even something like OAuth - could make it considerably easier to prevent duplicate votes.

Comment: ok i get it, so i cant do nothing only login to prevent duplicate votes:(

Comment: IP + cookie based systems generally work _well enough_. There is nothing that will stop hordes of 4chan/anonymous users from flooding your voting system ;)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use precise **and unique** properties of a client to check whether he/she has voted before or not,
**remember that there is no 100% accurate way to perform this action**
it's up to you how to make it harder for a client to be able to cheat, you can use SMS or Email verification, You can also retrieve and store client's mac address(as an example).